# How to manage two functions inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I'm using `useEffect` to fetch data. In my react use effect I have a function `profileApprove(false)` and a `refresh()` inside of the same `useEffect`. I do not want the refresh to start until profileApprove(false) is completed. At the moment I have a `setTimeOut` to handle the wait for profileApprove for me. I am getting what I want with the setTimeOut but unsure how to handle this properly.

```
export default function Profile() {
    const {
        profileApproved
    } = profileContext();
    function refresh() {
        dispatch({ type: "FECTH_PROFILE", payload: { loading: true } });
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        profileApproved(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
            refresh();
        }, 1000);
    }, []);
```

Comment: You should chain promise from profileApproved. Settimeout is not the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `profileApprove` method return a promise when done? If so just await on it before calling refresh

```
export default function Profile() {
    const {
        profileApproved
    } = profileContext();
    function refresh() {
        dispatch({ type: "FECTH_PROFILE", payload: { loading: true } });
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        profileApproved(false).then(refresh)
    }, []);
```

Comment: `async/await` adds so much noise in these kind of cases... `profileApproved(false).then(refresh)` reads so well already.